# Capibilities of CPT WordPress

Tags: custom-post-types, user-roles, capabilities

i create a 3 different custom post type and i need, on backend, this is ablet to edit only by administrator user role and my custom user role (mmv_multi_vendor).

I set capibilities on code but i have a problem. All user that have role "mmv_multi_vendor" see from backend the 3 CPT but user that have "administrator" role see on backend only CPT name "Resi".

This is my code:

```
/*CPT*/
/* Condizioni di Vendita */
add_action('init', 'crea_condizioni'); #[1]
function crea_condizioni() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'               => __('Archivio Condizioni'),
        'singular_name'      => __('Condizioni di Vendita'),
        'add_new'            => __('Aggiungi Condizioni di Vendita'),
        'add_new_item'       => __('Nuova Condizione di Vendita'),
        'edit_item'          => __('Modifica Condizione di Vendita'),
        'new_item'           => __('Nuova Codizione di Vendita'),
        'all_items'          => __('Elenco Condizioni di Vendita'),
        'view_item'          => __('Visualizza Condizione di Vendita'),
        'search_items'       => __('Cerca Condizione di Vendita'),
        'not_found'          => __('Condizione di Vendita non tovata'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('Condizione di Vendita non trovata nel cestino'),
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels'             => $labels, # [2]
        'public'             => true,    # [3]
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true, 
        'query_var' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'rewrite'            => array('slug' => 'condizioni'), # [4]
        'has_archive'        => 'salmi', # [5]
        'hierarchical'       => false, # [6]
        'menu_position'      => 5, # [7]
        'menu_icon'           => '',
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor' ),
        'map_meta_cap' => true,
        'capability_type' => array('crea_condizioni','crea_condizionis'),
    );
   register_post_type('condizioni', $args); #[9]
}
/* Condizioni Spedizione */
add_action('init', 'crea_spedizioni'); #[1]
function crea_spedizioni() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'               => __('Condizioni di Spedizione'),
        'singular_name'      => __('Condizioni di Spedizione'),
        'add_new'            => __('Aggiungi Condizione di Spedizione'),
        'add_new_item'       => __('Nuova Condizione di Spedizione'),
        'edit_item'          => __('Modifica Condizione di Spedizione'),
        'new_item'           => __('Nuova Condizione di Spedizione'),
        'all_items'          => __('Elenco Condizioni di Spedizione'),
        'view_item'          => __('Visualizza Condizione di Spedizione'),
        'search_items'       => __('Cerca Condizione di Spedizione'),
        'not_found'          => __('Condizione di Spedizione non trovata'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('Condizione di Spedizione non trovata nel cestino'),
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels'             => $labels, # [2]
        'public'             => true,    # [3]
        'rewrite'            => array('slug' => 'spedizioni'), # [4]
        'has_archive'        => true, # [5]
        'hierarchical'       => false, # [6]
        'menu_position'      => 6, # [7]
        'menu_icon'           => '',
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor' ),
        'map_meta_cap' => true,
        'capability_type' => array('crea_spedizioni','crea_spedizionis'),
    );
   register_post_type('spedizioni', $args); #[9]
}
/* Resi e Rimborsi */
add_action('init', 'crea_resi'); #[1]
function crea_resi() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'               => __('Resi e Rimborsi'),
        'singular_name'      => __('Resi e Rimborsi'),
        'add_new'            => __('Aggiungi Condizoni Resi e Rimborsi'),
        'add_new_item'       => __('Nuova Condizione Resi e Rimborsi'),
        'edit_item'          => __('Modifica Condizione Resi e Rimborsi'),
        'new_item'           => __('Nuova Condizione Resi e Rimborsi'),
        'all_items'          => __('Elenco Condizioni Resi e Rimborsi'),
        'view_item'          => __('Visualizza Condizioni Resi e Rimborsi'),
        'search_items'       => __('Cerca Condizioni Resi e Rimborsi'),
        'not_found'          => __('Nessuna Condizione Resi e Rimborsi trovata'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('Nessuna Resi e Rimborsi trovata nel cestino'),
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels'             => $labels, # [2]
        'public'             => true,    # [3]
        'rewrite'            => array('slug' => 'resi'), # [4]
        'has_archive'        => true, # [5]
        'hierarchical'       => false, # [6]
        'menu_position'      => 7, # [7]
        'menu_icon'           => '',
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor' ),
        'map_meta_cap' => true,
        'capability_type' => array('crea_resi','crea_resis'),
    );
   register_post_type('resi', $args); #[9]
}

// Caopibility Role

 add_action( 'init', 'add_bounty_product_caps');
    function add_bounty_product_caps() {
        global $wp_roles;

        if ( isset($wp_roles) ) {

          $wp_roles->add_cap( 'administrator', 'edit_crea_resi' ); 
          $wp_roles->add_cap( 'administrator', 'edit_crea_resis' ); 
          $wp_roles->add_cap( 'administrator', 'edit_others_crea_resis' ); 
          $wp_roles->add_cap( 'administrator', 'publish_crea_resis' ); 
          $wp_roles->add_cap( 'administrator', 'read_crea_resi' ); 
          $wp_roles->add_cap( 'administrator', 'read_private_crea_resis' ); 
          $wp_roles->add_cap( 'administrator', 'delete_crea_resi' ); 
          $wp_roles->add_cap( 'administrator', 'edit_published_crea_resis' );
          $wp_roles->add_cap( 'administrator', 'delete_published_crea_resis' );

          $wp_roles->add_cap( 'administrator', 'edit_crea_spedizioni' ); 
          $wp_roles->add_cap( 'administrator', 'edit_crea_spedizionis' ); 
          $wp_roles->add_cap( 'administrator', 'edit_others_crea_spedizionis' ); 
          $wp_roles->add_cap( 'administrator', 'publish_crea_spedizionis' ); 
          $wp_roles->add_cap( 'administrator', 'read_crea_spedizioni' ); 
          $wp_roles->add_cap( 'administrator', 'read_private_crea_spedizionis' ); 
          $wp_roles->add_cap( 'administrator', 'delete_crea_spedizioni' ); 
          $wp_roles->add_cap( 'administrator', 'edit_published_crea_spedizionis' );
          $wp_roles->add_cap( 'administrator', 'delete_published_crea_spedizionis' );

          $wp_roles->add_cap( 'administrator', 'edit_crea_condizioni' ); 
          $wp_roles->add_cap( 'administrator', 'edit_crea_condizionis' ); 
          $wp_roles->add_cap( 'administrator', 'edit_others_crea_condizionis' ); 
          $wp_roles->add_cap( 'administrator', 'publish_crea_condizionis' ); 
          $wp_roles->add_cap( 'administrator', 'read_crea_condizioni' ); 
          $wp_roles->add_cap( 'administrator', 'read_private_crea_condizionis' ); 
          $wp_roles->add_cap( 'administrator', 'delete_crea_condizioni' ); 
          $wp_roles->add_cap( 'administrator', 'edit_published_crea_condizionis' );
          $wp_roles->add_cap( 'administrator', 'delete_published_crea_condizionis' );

          $wp_roles->add_cap( 'mmv_multi_vendor', 'edit_crea_resi' ); 
          $wp_roles->add_cap( 'mmv_multi_vendor', 'edit_crea_resis' ); 
          $wp_roles->add_cap( 'mmv_multi_vendor', 'edit_others_crea_resis' ); 
          $wp_roles->add_cap( 'mmv_multi_vendor', 'publish_crea_resis' ); 
          $wp_roles->add_cap( 'mmv_multi_vendor', 'read_crea_resi' ); 
          $wp_roles->add_cap( 'mmv_multi_vendor', 'read_private_crea_resis' ); 
          $wp_roles->add_cap( 'mmv_multi_vendor', 'delete_crea_resi' ); 
          $wp_roles->add_cap( 'mmv_multi_vendor', 'edit_published_crea_resis' );
          $wp_roles->add_cap( 'mmv_multi_vendor', 'delete_published_crea_resis' );

          $wp_roles->add_cap( 'mmv_multi_vendor', 'edit_crea_spedizioni' ); 
          $wp_roles->add_cap( 'mmv_multi_vendor', 'edit_crea_spedizionis' ); 
          $wp_roles->add_cap( 'mmv_multi_vendor', 'edit_others_crea_spedizionis' ); 
          $wp_roles->add_cap( 'mmv_multi_vendor', 'publish_crea_spedizionis' ); 
          $wp_roles->add_cap( 'mmv_multi_vendor', 'read_crea_spedizioni' ); 
          $wp_roles->add_cap( 'mmv_multi_vendor', 'read_private_crea_spedizionis' ); 
          $wp_roles->add_cap( 'mmv_multi_vendor', 'delete_crea_spedizioni' ); 
          $wp_roles->add_cap( 'mmv_multi_vendor', 'edit_published_crea_spedizionis' );
          $wp_roles->add_cap( 'mmv_multi_vendor', 'delete_published_crea_spedizionis' );

          $wp_roles->add_cap( 'mmv_multi_vendor', 'edit_crea_condizioni' ); 
          $wp_roles->add_cap( 'mmv_multi_vendor', 'edit_crea_condizionis' ); 
          $wp_roles->add_cap( 'mmv_multi_vendor', 'edit_others_crea_condizionis' ); 
          $wp_roles->add_cap( 'mmv_multi_vendor', 'publish_crea_condizionis' ); 
          $wp_roles->add_cap( 'mmv_multi_vendor', 'read_crea_condizioni' ); 
          $wp_roles->add_cap( 'mmv_multi_vendor', 'read_private_crea_condizionis' ); 
          $wp_roles->add_cap( 'mmv_multi_vendor', 'delete_crea_condizioni' ); 
          $wp_roles->add_cap( 'mmv_multi_vendor', 'edit_published_crea_condizionis' );
          $wp_roles->add_cap( 'mmv_multi_vendor', 'delete_published_crea_condizionis' );

        }
  }
```

I also try to use only

```
 add_action( 'init', 'add_bounty_product_caps');
    function add_bounty_product_caps() {
        global $wp_roles;

        if ( isset($wp_roles) ) {

          $role = get_role( 'mmv_multi_vendor' );

          $role->add_cap( 'edit_crea_resi' ); 
          $role->add_cap( 'edit_crea_resis' ); 
          $role->add_cap( 'edit_others_crea_resis' ); 
          $role->add_cap( 'publish_crea_resis' ); 
          $role->add_cap( 'read_crea_resi' ); 
          $role->add_cap( 'read_private_crea_resis' ); 
          $role->add_cap( 'delete_crea_resi' ); 
          $role->add_cap( 'edit_published_crea_resis' );
          $role->add_cap( 'delete_published_crea_resis' );

          $role->add_cap( 'edit_crea_spedizioni' ); 
          $role->add_cap( 'edit_crea_spedizionis' ); 
          $role->add_cap( 'edit_others_crea_spedizionis' ); 
          $role->add_cap( 'publish_crea_spedizionis' ); 
          $role->add_cap( 'read_crea_spedizioni' ); 
          $role->add_cap( 'read_private_crea_spedizionis' ); 
          $role->add_cap( 'delete_crea_spedizioni' ); 
          $role->add_cap( 'edit_published_crea_spedizionis' );
          $role->add_cap( 'delete_published_crea_spedizionis' );

          $role->add_cap( 'edit_crea_condizioni' ); 
          $role->add_cap( 'edit_crea_condizionis' ); 
          $role->add_cap( 'edit_others_crea_condizionis' ); 
          $role->add_cap( 'publish_crea_condizionis' ); 
          $role->add_cap( 'read_crea_condizioni' ); 
          $role->add_cap( 'read_private_crea_condizionis' ); 
          $role->add_cap( 'delete_crea_condizioni' ); 
          $role->add_cap( 'edit_published_crea_condizionis' );
          $role->add_cap( 'delete_published_crea_condizionis' );
    }
```

But nothing change.

Thanks to all

Comment: What exactly is the challenge? Could you try rephrasing your post? It is hard to clearly understand what you intended to communicate.

Answer (score 0):

Adding custom capabilities should use the `'admin_init'` hook.

Your function can look like this:

```
function add_bounty_product_caps() {
    $role = get_role( 'mmv_multi_vendor' );

    $role->add_cap( 'edit_crea_resi' ); 
    $role->add_cap( 'edit_crea_resis' ); 
    $role->add_cap( 'edit_others_crea_resis' ); 
    $role->add_cap( 'publish_crea_resis' ); 
    $role->add_cap( 'read_crea_resi' ); 
    $role->add_cap( 'read_private_crea_resis' ); 
    $role->add_cap( 'delete_crea_resi' ); 
    $role->add_cap( 'edit_published_crea_resis' );
    $role->add_cap( 'delete_published_crea_resis' );

    $role->add_cap( 'edit_crea_spedizioni' ); 
    $role->add_cap( 'edit_crea_spedizionis' ); 
    $role->add_cap( 'edit_others_crea_spedizionis' ); 
    $role->add_cap( 'publish_crea_spedizionis' ); 
    $role->add_cap( 'read_crea_spedizioni' ); 
    $role->add_cap( 'read_private_crea_spedizionis' ); 
    $role->add_cap( 'delete_crea_spedizioni' ); 
    $role->add_cap( 'edit_published_crea_spedizionis' );
    $role->add_cap( 'delete_published_crea_spedizionis' );

    $role->add_cap( 'edit_crea_condizioni' ); 
    $role->add_cap( 'edit_crea_condizionis' ); 
    $role->add_cap( 'edit_others_crea_condizionis' ); 
    $role->add_cap( 'publish_crea_condizionis' ); 
    $role->add_cap( 'read_crea_condizioni' ); 
    $role->add_cap( 'read_private_crea_condizionis' ); 
    $role->add_cap( 'delete_crea_condizioni' ); 
    $role->add_cap( 'edit_published_crea_condizionis' );
    $role->add_cap( 'delete_published_crea_condizionis' );
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'add_bounty_product_caps' );
```

Comment: Hello thanks but no work. Now the problem is admin not display and mmv_multi_vendor can't edit a post after save.